# Issue tracker via Activiti

Tags: java, activiti, issue-tracking

Here is a problem to implement task tracker, which supports

1. tasks with statuses such as opened, in progress, hanging, resolved
2. simple workflows (i.e. signing document by multiple people http://i.gyazo.com/8247c0981cdf003a29a4783272eb4211.png)

According to the second requirement I am about to use Activiti in the development.

However, I have no idea how to add support of task statuses in Activiti. Built-in User Task can only be closed.

Workarounds:

1. To encapsulate statuses in code.  But I think it smells.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found early discussion on the same questions http://forums.activiti.org/content/user-task-set-task-priority-set-task-state